# Textarea using set_value not populated Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, textarea, validation, setvalue

i have a simple form in my view that has a text area :

```
<textarea name="description" value="<?php echo   set_value('description'); ?>"></textarea>
```

in my controller i have validated this text area using form_validation library

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
```

the validation is working perfectly , ie it gives me the error if text area is blank , but it does not repopulate the textarea , if textarea-description is correctly filled but there is some error in the other fields

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have a value attribute.

```
<textarea name="description"> 
      <?php echo set_value('description'); ?> 
</textarea>
```

Comment: could i be more stupid ? thanks alot , that was quick and perfect

Comment: Yes you can. It is the third paremeter if you are using the form helper.

Comment: iam using 

     <?php echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map,  '', 'id="_pro"') ?>

Comment: `<?php echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map, set_value('mid'), 'id="promotion_product"') ?>`

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question. Please ask a new question and post the code you tried and the errors you received.

Answer (score 0):

If value return only form_validation:

```
<?=form_textarea(array('name'=>'description'),set_value('description'));?>
```

If the value is elsewhere:

```
<?=form_textarea(array('name'=>'description'),set_value('description',$value));?>
```

Documentation CodeIgniter:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

> form_textarea() This function is identical in all respects to the
>   form_input() function above except that it generates a "textarea"
>   type. Note: Instead of the "maxlength" and "size" attributes in the
>   above example, you will instead specify "rows" and "cols".